# Silent push notification for some notification with a particular payload

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications

I'm trying to Hide some specified Push notification's from the user so that it won't be visible for user.
Where can I write the conditions for hiding the notifications on arrival for it to not to display in the notification Tray.
I tried doing it in `AppDelgate` but didn't work. Is there any other way I can do this ?

```
func application(applxication: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification)
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(<#T##notification: UILocalNotification##UILocalNotification#>)
        //println("Local Notification Received:\(notification)")
    }
```

It would be of Great help if you could help me out here.

Comment: I am also looking to hide received push notifications. Anyone knows how this can be handled?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this for remote notification, not for local notification. 
So as per the Apple WWDC 2013, if you will pass `content-available" : 1` in your pay load, then it will act as silent push notification.

So just include `content-available" : 1` in your payload as shown below to get a silent notification.

Also in App’s `Info.plist` should have `UIBackgroundModes set to remote-notification`
More info here [For Silent push notification](http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/)

```
{
    aps = {
        "content-available" : 1,
        sound : ""
    };
}
```

Hope it helps ...

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you @janmenjaya... Is there a way to handle this from the app side, even if i have the "content-available" as  "0" ?

Comment: You can check the "content-available" in delegate to know which is silent notification and which is not. I think You are asking this

Comment: Like this :    if ([[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"content-available"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) {
}

Comment: no , what i meant was in the payload if i receive "content-available" : 0 , from the app how will i be able to hide/NotShow that particular notification.

Comment: I think you can not hide then. This is the reason why Apple introduced Silent notification, If it was possible then they might not have brought this new technique in the WWDC 2013

Answer (score 1):

set

> content-available" : 1

and remove

> body

and

> alert

from payload.

This will give you desired result.

When this type of push is received by your app, it'll call the following method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way to handle it through the app while the "content-available" is "0"?

Comment: yes, you can. but it'll be limited to Running and background mode only. you wont be able to receive or handle it if content-available is set to 0 while your app is offline.